# Make ischrone/service area/distance shed along a network in python

Tags: python, networking, graph, gis, distance

I have a network and I'd like to create service areas around points on this network, as shown

[image]
(I've done it in ArcGIS but I'd like to do it just with a python script)

where the purple lines and green points are the edges and nodes of a network respectively, the orange point is the point I am measuring the distance from, and the orange polygons are the service areas at various distances.

I've created the road network with edges and nodes with networkx. With networkx we can measure distances between nodes of a network, but with service areas we're measuring distances not up to the next node but partway along the edge i.e. until the distance limit is reached from a central point. So just wondering how I can achieve this in python, any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Consider throwing your location data into a postgres table. And then take advantage of the excellent [GIS support](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html). It is very fast, even when querying large tables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: " the orange polygons are ... " I can only see one orange polygon

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what this question is about.

It seems that 'distance sheds' ( whatever THEY might be ) are likely irrelevant to what looks like the crucial question

"how I can compute distance along a network without using the nodes?"

Presumably you have the node locations ( latitude and longitude, perhaps? )  If this is the ONLY information you have, then, of course, you cannot calculate distances of anything other than nodes.

So, you need to tell us

- what information DO you have
- what distances do you need to measure.

Comment: Hello, I've edited the question. I have edges and nodes of the network and am wanting to calculate distance from a starting node along the edges rather than just between nodes (the latter being something I know is possible with networkx). Hopefully that's clearer, thanks.